# How to transform a DB payload to JSON array in mulesoft?

Tags: integration, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, anypoint-studio

[attached my input payload for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFJtk.png)my expected output is
[

{
"ID": 1,
"code": "IND5321",
"DepartureDate": "2/10/2023",
"Origin": "CHN",
"Destination":  "KNR",
"availableSeats": 30
},
{
"ID": 2,
"code": "IND6453",
"DepartureDate": "4/10/2023",
"Origin": "CHN",
"Destination": "AMN",
"availableSeats": 60
},
{
"ID": 3,
"code":"IND5987",
"DepartureDate": "3/10/2023",
"Origin": "CHN",
"Destination": "TVM",
"availableSeats": 47
}
]

but my actual output is:

{
"ID": [
1,
2,
3
],
"code": [
"IND5321",
"IND6453",
"IND5987"
],
"departureDate": [
"2/11/2023",
"4/11/2023",
"3/11/2023"
],
"origin": [
"CHN",
"CHN",
"CHN"
],
"destination": [
"KNR",
"AMN",
"TVM"
],
"availableSeats": [
"30",
"60",
"47"
]
}

How can I transform the database payload to JSON array?

Comment: What is your input? To get help you should provide details about the input and what you tried. Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please provide  the input for this transform.Please use [code format](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) for code/samples.

Comment: Please **do not** post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. Code or sample data in images can't be copied and pasted in order to search about a problem or reproduce it. You should provide an example input like your example outputs, in text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your actual output I'm assuming that the input is an array of similar information to the output but you want to transform some data. You can use the [map()](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.5/dw-core-functions-map) function to transform each item in the array.

Example:

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload map {
    ID: $.ID,
    code: $.CODE,
    DepartureDate: $.DEPARTUREDATE
    // other mappings...
}
```

What you are doing is probably something like `payload.ID` for each key which returns an array of all the IDs in the input array.

Comment: attached my input payload

Comment: Key names are case-sensitive. You need to use the same key name so DataWeave can find the right key. I have updated my example. Are you having any issues trying this solution?

Comment: its working.. Thank you

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers on the recommended process for useful responses.